# How to filter several strings

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

For the following lines, I need to filter out only protocol, port, and service.

```
tcp 127.0.0.1:25  1147/master
tcp 0.0.0.0:443  1039/nginx:
tcp 127.0.0.1:8001  1218/python
tcp 0.0.0.0:10050  939/zabbix_agentd
tcp 127.0.0.1:6379  891/redis-server
tcp 0.0.0.0:80  1039/nginx:
tcp 0.0.0.0:22  889/sshd
tcp 127.0.0.1:5432  929/postmaster
udp 127.0.0.1:323 645/chronyd
```

I need it like this:

```
tcp 25 master
tcp 443 nginx
tcp 8001 python
tcp 10050 zabbix_agentd
tcp 6379 redis-server
tcp 80 nginx
tcp 22 sshd
tcp 5432 postmaster
udp 323 chronyd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
sed -re 's/[^ ]+://' -e 's# +[0-9]+/# #' -e 's/:$//'
```

Explanation:

- `sed -r` - use sed in extended-regexp mode
- `-e 's/[^ ]+://'` - remove everything before the first colon backwards until a space
- `-e 's# +[0-9]+/# #'` - replace any number of spaces, a number, and a slash with a single space
- `-e 's/:$//'` - remove a colon from the end of the line

Answer (score 5):

This seems more straightforward and easy to remember. The `-F` option to AWK allows you to provide a regular expression class that includes the characters you need to split on.

```
awk -F'[ :/]' '{print $1,$3,$5}' file
```

steve (below) mentioned a shorter way than I originally thought of:

- Instead of `cat file | ...` just put the file at the end.
- Commas in between dollar items add spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file | sed 's/[:/]/\t/g' | awk '{print $1 " " $3 " " $5}'
tcp 25 master
tcp 443 nginx
tcp 8001 python
tcp 10050 zabbix_agentd
tcp 6379 redis-server
tcp 80 nginx
tcp 22 sshd
tcp 5432 postmaster
udp 323 chr

sed 's/[:/]/\t/g' convert `:` and '/` to tab
```

Answer (score 2):

With a single `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ print $1, gensub( /^.*:/, "", "1", $2 ), gensub( /[0-9]+\//, "", "1", $3 ) }' input
tcp 25 master
tcp 443 nginx:
tcp 8001 python
tcp 10050 zabbix_agentd
tcp 6379 redis-server
tcp 80 nginx:
tcp 22 sshd
tcp 5432 postmaster
udp 323 chronyd
```